# Sort a list of strings by second-to-last character

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I need to sort a list of strings using character comparison starting with penultimate element moving down to the beginning of string (for equal characters). so basically I need to get this

```
in_ = ['message', 'essagem', 'ssageme', 'sagemes', 'agemess', 'gemessa', 'emessag']

result = ['emessag', 'essagem', 'sagemes', 'message', 'ssageme', 'agemess', 'gemessa']
# sorted on second to last character in each string
```

Comment: I do not see any sorting. I only notice "rotating" a string (so to speak). Furthermore: what have you tried?

Comment: `>>> m="message"; m[-1]+m[:-1]`

Comment: It's not rotation either, #1 stays the same... The criteria to modify the string is unclear!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: this two columns - two lists. 1st one is unsorted(it's a list of left shifts) so I need to sort it, 2nd one is sorted(look at penultimate characters). thanks for -1 btw

Comment: @emptylungs I've edited the question to appear more clear, since a whole heap of us didn't understand as originally phrased.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want? If yes, make that penultimate letter the key for the `sort()` function.

```
a = ['message', 'essagem', 'ssageme', 'sagemes', 'agemess', 'gemessa', 'emessag']
a.sort(key=lambda x:x[-2])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['emessag', 'essagem', 'sagemes', 'message', 'ssageme', 'agemess', 'gemessa']
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add something alternative to Miraj50's answer: You can do it using `itemgetter` too in a bit [cleaner/faster way](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

```
from operator import itemgetter

in_list = ['message', 'essagem', 'ssageme', 'sagemes', 'agemess', 'gemessa', 'emessag']
result = sorted(in_list, key=itemgetter(-2))
print(result)
```

output:

```
['emessag', 'essagem', 'sagemes', 'message', 'ssageme', 'agemess', 'gemessa']
```